# Block always returning nil

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to record a `UIView` animation for a WatchKit app.  First, I implemented the function with out the block which return zero frames being recorded.  This was due to the `[recorder stop]` being called before the animation completed (I think). So, I added a completion block.  Now, it never has `self.completion` is `YES`.  I want the completion block to notify me when the animation is complete.  What am I missing here?

ViewController.m

```
-(void)runAnimation{

ALBatteryView *batteryView = [[ALBatteryView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)];
  [self.batteryIcon addSubview:batteryView];
  recorder.view = _batteryIcon;
  [recorder start];
  [batteryView setBatteryLevelWithAnimation:YES forValue:[UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevelInPercentage inPercent:YES];
  CGFloat batteryPer = [UBattery batteryLevel];
  batteryPercentage.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%", batteryPer];
  battery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%", batteryPer];
  [batteryView batteryAnaminationWithCompletion:^(BOOL finished){
    if (finished){
      [recorder stop];
    }
  }];
}
```

AlBatteryView.h

```
@interface ALBatteryView : UIView {
UIView *batteryFill;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) void(^completion)(BOOL finished);

- (void)setBatteryLevelWithAnimation:(BOOL)isAnimated forValue:(CGFloat)batteryLevel inPercent:(BOOL)inPercent;
- (void)reload;
- (void)batteryAnaminationWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
@end
```

ALBatteryView.m

```
- (void)setBatteryLevelWithAnimation:(BOOL)isAnimated forValue:(CGFloat)batteryLevel inPercent:(BOOL)inPercent {

  // Declare the newWidth and save the correct battery level
  // based on inPercent value
  CGFloat newWidth;
  CGFloat newBatteryLevel = (inPercent) ? batteryLevel : batteryLevel * 100;
  // Set the new width
  newWidth = kOnePercent * newBatteryLevel;
  // If animated proceed with the animation
  // else assign the value without animates

  if (isAnimated)
      [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
          /* This direct assignment is possible
           * using the UIView+ALQuickFrame category
           * http://github.com/andrealufino/ALQuickFrame */
          batteryFill.width = newWidth;
          // Set the color based on battery level
          batteryFill.backgroundColor = [self setColorBasedOnBatteryLevel:newBatteryLevel];
          if (self.completion) {
              self.completion(YES);
          }
      }];

  else
      batteryFill.width = newWidth;

}
-(void)batteryAnaminationWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion{
  self.completion = completion;
}
```

Comment: why dont you want to use `[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    } completion: (BOOL finished) {
   }];` and delegates ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your completion block before starting the animation (change code order).

Then, your block should be declared as copy.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^completion)(BOOL finished);
```

Then, delete the (wrongly named) batteryAnaminationWithCompletion method altogether, and just use the property:

```
batteryView.completion = ...
```

Comment: The comment from @Oyeoj works fine.  I'm not following you way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your block property before you call for the animation (`setBatteryLevelWithAnimation`).  Otherwise it will be `nil` when you try to access it before it's set.

Also you should set your block property directly, it will be more clear, because that's what your `-batteryAnaminationWithCompletion` method does (btw it should be spelled "Animation")
From:

```
  [batteryView batteryAnaminationWithCompletion:^(BOOL finished){
    if (finished){
      [recorder stop];
    }
  }];
```

To:

```
  [batteryView setCompletion:^(BOOL finished){
    if (finished){
      [recorder stop];
    }
  }];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading it right,

When you call -(void)runAnimation 
it calls the animation block right here and animation block will referencing the completion which is nil at the moment

```
  [batteryView setBatteryLevelWithAnimation:YES forValue:[UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevelInPercentage inPercent:YES];
```

If you are thinking animationWithDuration call the block 2 second later than.. it's wrong.. self.completion is nil at the moment and animation's duration is 2 second but self.completion is not animatable and it calls right up front.. you need some kind of lock if you want to wait this animation to be finished.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        /* This direct assignment is possible
         * using the UIView+ALQuickFrame category
         * http://github.com/andrealufino/ALQuickFrame */
        batteryFill.width = newWidth;
        // Set the color based on battery level
        batteryFill.backgroundColor = [self setColorBasedOnBatteryLevel:newBatteryLevel];
        if (self.completion) {
                    self.completion(YES);
        }
    }];
```

Just print out NSLog before animateWithDuration and NSLog from inside of block to see when if (self.completion) is referenced..

Answer (score 0):

The interface is unduly complex if the only objective is animation. There's no need for a block property at all. Consider the following...

```
// ALBatteryView.h
@interface ALBatteryView : UIView

// up to you, but I'd clean up the animating interface by making a property of this class determine
// how it handles levels in all cases as either absolute or %
@property(assign, nonatomic) BOOL inPercent;

// use naming style like the sdk...
- (void)setBatteryLevel:(CGFloat)batteryLevel animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL))completion;

@end
```

In the implementation...

```
// ALBatteryView.m
@interface ALBatteryView ()

// hide the internal view property here.  make it weak, and assign it after [self subView:...
@property(weak,nonatomic) UIView *batteryFill;

@end
```

In just that one animation method, using a few tricks in UIView animation, you can accomplish everything that it looks like you need...

```
- (void)setBatteryLevel:(CGFloat)batteryLevel animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL))completion {

    // one trick is that UIView animation with zero duration just
    // changes the animatable properties and calls its completion block
    NSTimeInterval duration = (animated)? 2.0 : 0.0;

    CGFloat newBatteryLevel = (self.inPercent)? batteryLevel : batteryLevel * 100;
    CGFloat newWidth = kOnePercent * newBatteryLevel;
    // don't name that color-returning method "set" color.  The "set" part happens here...
    UIColor *newColor = [self colorBasedOnBatteryLevel:newBatteryLevel];

    // now, the animation in just one shot, passing the block parameter
    // which has the same signature as the UIView animation block param
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        self.batteryFill.width = newWidth;
        self.batteryFill.backgroundColor = newColor;
    } completion:completion]; 
}
```